# How do I create a literal control character in Kate?

Tags: command-line, keyboard, kate, ascii

I frequently use the ASCII character 31 ( Unit Separator; `Ctrl-_` ) as a field delimiter for the work that I do.

Using the bash command line, I can enter a literal control character by pressing `Ctrl-V` then the control character.  (I use `Ctrl-V`, then `Shift-Ctrl-_` when specifying delimiters for cut or sort commands).

How do I enter this control character using the Kate text editor?

Comment: Some research shows 2 methods but only one works

1.   <SHIFT>+<CTRL>+U + hex code + <enter>  (Doesn't work)

2.  <F7> to open command mode then 'char 0x<hex code><enter>' (Does work but kludgy)  

There has to be a better way

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the <kbd>F7</kbd> to enter command mode works pretty well, after all.

The char function is not limited to just hex codes, decimal values work just as well.

Hitting <kbd>F7</kbd> to enter command mode then entering `char 31` produces exactly what I needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found out that I can insert checkboxes from unicode like this: ```F7``` + ```char 0x2610```, ```char 0x2611``` or ```char 0x2612```. Helps me a lot. Thanks!